# jQuery - get <li> from <ul> with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, html-lists

I have a list:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li class="one">Item A</li>
   <li class="one">Item B</li>
   <li class="two">Item C</li>
   <div id="pressed">Submit</div>
</ul>
```

and when "Submit" is pressed I want to retrieve the value of the list item which has a class of "two". In this instance, pressed Submit would return "Item C". Here's the jQuery I've tried:

```
$("#pressed").click(function() {
   var v = $('#list').filter('.two').val();
   alert(v);
});
```

But all this returns is `0`. What's the best way to do this? Only one `<li>` will have a class of "two" at any one time.

Comment: Li's don't have a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need html() or text() instead of val(). The function val() is used for input elements like text, checkbox etc. Also put div outside ul to make your html valid as Rory McCrossan pointed

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/cGn2D/1/)

```
var v = $('#list').filter('.two').html();
```

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid as `div` elements cannot be children of `ul`:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li class="one">Item A</li>
   <li class="one">Item B</li>
   <li class="two">Item C</li>
</ul>
<div id="pressed">Submit</div>
```

Secondly, `text()` is the property you want, not `val()`:

```
$("#pressed").click(function() {
   var v = $('#list').find('.two').text();
   alert(v);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cGn2D/)

Comment: For really proper HTML you should also use either an anchor tag (`<a href="#" id="pressed">Submit</a>`) or a button tag (`<button id="pressed">Submit</button>`) for anything that's clickable.

Comment: @max_w Source please...although I don't necessarily disagree.

Comment: @max_w from an accessibilty point I agree. However there are certain cases where that is just not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I made a generalisation in my statement. Most times (and most certainly in the case of the example in this question) an anchor tag or a button should be used for clickable elements. The benefits of using them include getting `cursor: pointer` by default, getting the `tabindex` on the element set by default, and identifying the tags as clickable with screen readers. I do agree that sometimes they aren't he best fit though (like when you're trying to make a block element which contains nested elements clickable).

Comment: @max_w completely agree

Answer (score 1):

After Rory McCrossan's correction with HTML you can do this.

```
$("#pressed").click(function() {
   alert($('#list .two').text());
});
```